# Returning Complex Function Responses

Tags: php

How can I create a generic and common system of returning application code and response messages upwards when an API call is called?

For example, I have a `User` class in `user.php`. From the highest level of my application, let's say `app.php` we can call

```
$user = new User();
$user->register($params);
```

About 10 things can go wrong during that process:

- user already exists
- invalid parameters
- etc..

I don't want to just return 0 or 1, I also want the caller to know what was wrong. Here are some ideas

1. Exceptions, which I seriously hate..
2. Return array responses, ie `['result'=>0, 'reason'=>'not unique']`

What is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: I would go for custom exceptions, definitelly

Comment: Exceptions for error states, objects for complex success responses.

Comment: Do it in different steps. Before creating the user object, validate the data (including checking for duplicates etc.). There are many validation libraries you can use and extend for this.

Comment: "Exceptions, which I seriously hate." Why? They're incredibly useful and the standard for a good reason.

Comment: @ceejayoz I just don't like the try catch block I guess. No real good reason. I also feel like, as others have said, an exception should only occur when something horribly wrong has happened.

Comment: Something horribly wrong *has* happened - the API call the user attempted has *failed*! No need for a try/catch block everywhere, either - you can set up application-wide exception handling to output a meaningful, consistent error response. Take a look at how Laravel does it for examples.

Answer (score 2):

You asked about the *standard* way of handling this kind of thing. Generally the best way to handle these sorts of errors is by using exceptions, your dislike of them notwithstanding. By using exceptions, you can get away with doing less work on each side of the interface (method and caller) when you add a new kind of failure condition.  You get code that's easier to maintain and more resilient to change. It's also higher performance: exceptions have a performance cost, but only when you raise them.

Your approach of returning arrays or objects is also OK. But you'll have to adjust both sides of the interface when you add new conditions.

There's a writeup on this in the php manual here.  http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: I would not use exceptions here.  Exceptions should be used for unexpected conditions about wich nothing can be done. Like a hardware or network problem. In this case "user already exists" or "invalid parameters" are perfectly predictable problems and should be treated appropriately.

Comment: @FrédéricClausset And how would you return, from a function, both a status and a status message response?

Comment: @J Doe I would return only a status and put the message in the documentation of the API. What's the use of a message for another computer ? But we disgress :-)

Comment: @FrédéricClausset I disagree, strongly. `try/catch` exists because exceptions are *intended* to sometimes be things you can catch and do something about. Laravel, for example, throws a `ValidationException` for validation failures.

Comment: @ceejayoz : yes I also agreee with your point of vieuw. Truly ... maybe the problem is in the question. There is no "standard way", just a matter of taste....